# undestanding c program gauss-jordan elimination

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix

i know i sound stupid but i really need to understand the gauss-jordan elimination c program. i already try to understand the coding but it's still confusing for to read the code line by line.Especially the  for(j=1; j<=n; j++) loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,j,k,n;
float A[20][20],c,x[10];
printf("\nEnter the size of matrix: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\nEnter the elements of augmented matrix row-wise:\n");
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=(n+1); j++)
    {
        printf(" A[%d][%d]:", i,j);
        scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
    }
}

for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
{
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(i!=j)
        {
            c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];
            for(k=1; k<=n+1; k++)
            {
                A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("\nThe solution is:\n");
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    x[i]=A[i][n+1]/A[i][i];
    printf("\n x%d=%f\n",i,x[i]);
}
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take an example augmented matrix

```
 1 1 1 | 5
 2 3 5 | 8
 4 0 5 | 2
```

The main aim is to make all the elements of matrix 0 except the elements at position where i==j.

so in the second for loop,when the if condition is true for the first time i=2 j=1,A[2][1]=2
So to make A[2][1]=0 we have to subtract 2.This 2 we get from `c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];` Hence we will perform **R2-2R1** (row2-2*row1) operation `A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];`

Similarly operations are performed for all the rows.

Comment: This is just from a first look at the code. To understand more you can use a debugger and execute line by line